# Erlang Web and Inets BindAddress

Tags: erlang, inets, erlangweb

After installing Erlang Web 1.3 and starting it in interactive mode, I get the following error in the logs:

> Failed to start service:
>   "config/inets.conf"
>   due to: "httpd_conf: 0.0.0.0 is an
>   invalid address"

In my inets.conf I have the following:

```
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
```

My sys.config:

```
[{inets,[{services,[{httpd,"config/inets.conf"}]}]}].
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I know nothing about erlang, but wouldn't the first thing to try be to change the 0.0.0.0? Maybe try a nice 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself.

I just changed the BindAddress line in inets.conf into:

```
BindAddress *
```

Answer (score 1):

This configuration directive is being parsed and validated by [`httpd_conf`](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/blob/master/lib/inets/src/http_server/httpd_conf.erl#L234), which in turn calls [`httpd_util:ip_address/2`](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/blob/master/lib/inets/src/http_server/httpd_util.erl#L38).  Both of these were changed in R13B02.  Have you tried with that Erlang/OTP version?

Comment: Done. Same problem. I started the following discussion on the Erlang bugs mailing list: http://www.erlang.org/cgi-bin/ezmlm-cgi?2:mss:1565:200910:dbklgbgeplapjeofpjmo

Answer (score 0):

i have no experience with this language or situation, but it looks like that 0.0.0.0 is an invalid address, have you tried changing it to something like 127.0.0.1 ?